# NSTableView view based changed cell elements position after scrolling

Tags: cocoa

i was using nstablewview to setup messaging.
everything work fine while scrolling not starting:

[image]

Then, if scrolling was started, sometimes elents with SAME frame(i was logged frame parameters inside tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:) parameters visible bellow correct position inside cell:

[image]

looks like bug in apple code, but maybe somebody know, how it can be fixed?

setFrame:
called from 2 places -

[NSView resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] ()

and from

tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:

gives a same data as final (correct) frame....

```
2012-12-06 18:40:20.283[99782:303] setFrame->{{0, -7},{219.4296875,56}}   
2012-12-06 18:40:43.086[99782:303] message.frame->{{20, 3}, {179.4296875, 36}} background.frame->{{0,-7}, {219.4296875, 56}}
2012-12-06 18:38:46.296 [99782:303] setFrame->{{0, -7}, {219, 56}}
```

Comment: Add some logging or a breakpoint to the `setFrame` method of that view to see if it's called.

Comment: @trojanfoe please review updates...